# Converting binary PNG mask to 'label indicator matrix' format to be evaluated using sklearn.metrics f1_score (binary)

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am training a CNN using TensorFlow, python, and Keras. I want to evaluate the accuracy of my models using `sklearn.metrics.f1_score` and `sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score`. However, when I try to use these metrics it says that multilabel-indicators are not supported. Which means it thinks my data is multi-label versus binary?

However, my data are 2D arrays uint8 with values of `0.` or `1.` therefore they are binary. Are there any simple ways to convert my data into the binary label indicator matrix format? It works when I use `f1_score(...,average = 'micro')`. Image and label example below.

[image: example image (.jpg)]
[image: example label (ground truth) (.png)]

This is how I am currently processing images...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from glob import glob
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, cohen_kappa_score



sz = (128,128)

# between lines occurs within a generator object
#--------------------------------------------#
raw = Image.open('image_path/image.jpg')
raw = raw.resize(sz)
raw = np.array(raw)

if len(raw.shape) == 2:
    raw = np.stack((raw,)*3, axis = 1
else:
    raw[:,:,0:3]/255

mask = Image.open('label_path/label.png')
mask = np.array(mask.resize(sz))
mask[mask == 0] = 0
mask[mask > 0] = 1

X = raw
Y = mask

#---------------#

thresh = .5
pred = model.predict(np.expand_dims(X,0) # keras CNN model
pred = pred.squeeze()
pred = np.stack((pred,)*3, axis = 1)
pred[pred >= thresh] = 1
pred[pred < thresh] = 0
ypred = pred

ytrue = Y.squeeze()

f1_value = f1_score(ytrue, ypred, pos_lab = 1, average = 'binary')
kappa_value = cohen_kappa_score(ytrue, ypred)


# output

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-ea23b72879e2> in <module>()

--->17   f1_value = f1_score(ytrue,ypred,pos_label = 1, average = 'binary')
    18   kappa_value = cohen_kappa_score(ytrue, ypred)


1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels, sample_weight, normalize)
    268     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    269     if y_type not in ("binary", "multiclass"):
--> 270         raise ValueError("%s is not supported" % y_type)
    271 
    272     if labels is None:

ValueError: multilabel-indicator is not supported
```

It's weird because the data only contains 0s and 1s, so why does it think it is a multilabel-indicator rather than binary?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work by flattening both arrays

```
ytrueF = ytrue.flatten()
ypredF = ypred.flatten()

f1 = f1_score(ytrueF, ypredF, pos_label = 1, average = 'binary')
kappa = cohen_kappa_score(ytrueF, ypredF)
```

However, I am still looking for a good guide for preprocessing imagery for binary segmentation